# PHP diz que duas strings iguais têm comprimentos diferentes

Tags: php, string

Estou querendo comparar duas strings porém acontece algo bastante inusitado. Tenho o código:

```
<?php
$char = 'Á';

var_dump('Á');          
var_dump($char);
```

A variável `$char` recebe 'Á' e o resultado  é o seguinte.

```
string 'Ã' (length=2)
string 'Ã' (length=1)
```

Valores exatamente iguais porém com tamanhos diferentes. Alguma ideia do porque disso?

Comment: qual o código que vc esta usando para comparar ?

Comment: Por favor explique melhor o problema, e se possível inclua um [exemplo de código que reproduza o que está acontecendo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), pois está ampla demais a sua pergunta. [Veja na Central de Ajuda Como Perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Não consigo reproduzir http://ideone.com/yuQrKO

Comment: @bfavaretto chuto que o encoding do script dele não seja UTF-8.

Comment: @gmsantos, exato.. também acho que seja isso.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Se você quer comparar strings que têm `acentos` ou `special char`, a melhor forma é **mb_***
[mb_strlen](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mb-strlen.php) para contar a quantidade de caracteres

> A questão não tem relação com codificação UTF, da mesma forma que as funções nativas para comparação de string apresentam diferença com `acentos` ou `special char`.

```
strlen( 'aviao' ) // 5
strlen( 'avião' ) // 6
mb_strlen( 'avião' , 'utf-8' ) // 5
```

É a forma como o PHP trata `acentos` ou `special char`.
`var_dump` servre apenas para retornar uma informação visual sobre um elemento e é passível de conflito na interpretação de tais caracteres.